# Obtain network location description of laptop/pc using asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to build one web form that is used in multiple locations (four) on one WLAN. Is there a way to obtain the network location description of the laptop/pc logged onto the website in order to pass a variable through to the site to help determine the area so as to eliminate the issue of having the users to have to enter their location into the system?  The webform will be written in asp.net